# When I process a data array from an API it says it is empty AND not empty

Tags: reactjs, arrays, api, next.js, async-await

I am trying to process an array called from an API. I call the API in an async function and use the await keyword on the line with the api call.

I tried to console.log the results of the call and I get this. [image: console.log results] I am confused why the initial heading says Array(78) indicating it is an array of length 78 but then when I look at the specific contents of the array it says it is length 0 and empty. When I try to use the data array from the call it is an empty array. I expected the array to be of length 78 and be full of data I can use.

Comment: Browser consoles usually display live references to values, meaning if the value of the printed value changes later in JavaScript, the value below the fold will update as well. So something in your code is mutating the `data` property by the time you inspect it in the console.

Comment: please provide client side code and server side if you have it

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)